# How to resize an Image that a user uploaded and store it in a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Hello guys I've read a lot of articles about resizing an image and storing it into SQL.

Before I post my problem, I will explain more: I'm working in WinForms, with SQL database. Users will upload images into SQL.

I want to resize the Image before storing it. The uploaded image will be in shown in a PictureBox.

The SQL data type is `Image`.

Here is my code in uploading image:

```
private void BUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CmbImo.SelectedIndex != -1) { 
        OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Filter = "Image Files(*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg)|*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png;*.jpg";

        if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            pictureBox1.Text = open.FileName;
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(open.FileName);
            pictureBox1.Image = resizeImage(pictureBox1.Image, new Size(430, 344));
        }
        else
        {
            label2.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            label2.Text = "Are you sure you dont want to upload an image !!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Do Select an Imo !!");
    }
    pictureBox1.Visible = true;
}
```

Here is my resize procedure:

```
public static Image resizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
{
    return (Image)(new Bitmap(imgToResize, size));
}
```

Here is my insert into the table:

```
public void SaveATLast()
{
    cnx.Close();
    string image = pictureBox1.Text;

    if (CmbImo.SelectedIndex != -1 && textBox1.Text!="" && textBox3.Text != "")
    { 
        cnx.Open();
            // string image = pictureBox1.Text;
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(image);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(image, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] bimage = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(bimage, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

        fs.Close();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" insert into Baa (Imo, Height, Name, ImageB, BPlug, APlug) values (@Imo, @Height, @Name, @imgdata, @BPlug, @APlug)", cnx);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CmbImo.SelectedItem.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgdata", SqlDbType.Image).Value = bimage;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BPlug", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APlug", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox2.Text;
        comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cnx.Close();

        // this.Close();
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox4.Clear();
        pictureBox1.Image = null;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please do fill out all textboxes!");
    }
}
```

Just to be more clear , user upload image it gets into PictureBox, in the PictureBox its actually RESIZED but once the use clicks on add button where `SaveAtLast()` is called it actually save the image into table with the normal size and not the resized one that is actually in the PictureBox.

I really hope it has nothing to do with the type of image because I read somehow people recommend to use `VarBinary` instead of `Image`.

Thanks in advance guys.

**EDIT :**
please guysi dont know if this is marked as resolved or not for everyone thats having the same issue with these images insertion to sql please do read the comments below Dai and Habib Comment is what helped me undertsand whats going on in this byte images and the how storing is done , plus this article if you could read about it as well 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25956/Sending-Receiving-PictureBox-Image-in-C-To-From-Mi

Comment: You need to use the `Graphics` object to resize an image.

Comment: The `image` datatype in T-SQL is obsolete. Its replacement is `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: See [Graphics.FromImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage), [Graphics.DrawImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage), [Graphics.InterpolationMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.interpolationmode),  (`InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic`), [Graphics.PixelOffsetMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.pixeloffsetmode) (`PixelOffsetMode.Half`). As already suggested, ditch the `Image` data type.

Comment: Maybe second time is the charm? don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your image resize code. In `SaveATLast` function you are loading image again from the file which is the original one not modified because the modified image is in `pictureBox1`.

You should get the modified image from `pictureBox1` to save in DB, not from the file.

```
public void SaveATLast()
{
    cnx.Close();
    string image = pictureBox1.Text;

    if (CmbImo.SelectedIndex != -1 && textBox1.Text!="" && textBox3.Text != "")
    { 
        cnx.Open();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms,pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
            byte[] bimage = new byte[ms.Length];
            ms.Write(bimage, 0, (int)ms.Length);
            //DB Opeartions stuff
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" insert into Baa ( Imo , Height  ,Name , ImageB,BPlug,APlug) values ( @Imo, @Height , @Name , @imgdata,@BPlug,@APlug)", cnx);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = CmbImo.SelectedItem.ToString();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Height", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@imgdata", SqlDbType.Image).Value = bimage;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BPlug", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@APlug", SqlDbType.Int).Value = textBox2.Text;
            comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cnx.Close();
        }

        //this.Close();
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox4.Clear();
        pictureBox1.Image = null;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("please Do Fill all Textboxes !!");
    }
}
```

**Edited**

> This will save the image as an uncompressed DIB BMP image, which is an
>   inefficient use of space. @Dai

So we should use `Graphics` for image scaling.

```
public static Image resizeImage(Image image, int width, int height)
{
    var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
    var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height);

    destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    }

    return destImage;
}
```

and use `resizeImage` function inside `SaveATLast`

```
var scaledImage = ResizeImage(Image.FromFile(pictureBox1.Text), 430, 344);
var ms = new MemoryStream();
scaledImage.Save(ms, scaledImage.RawFormat);
byte[] bimage = new byte[ms.Length];
ms.Write(bimage, 0, (int)ms.Length);
ms.Close();
```

Comment: This will save the image as an uncompressed DIB BMP image, which is an inefficient use of space.

Comment: Okay. Then load image from the file and modify the size when saving in DB.

Comment: The updated code you've posted still does not compress the BMP image at all. Also, the `PictureBox` does not actually provide a resized (scale-transformed) image - `pictureBox.Image` always returns the the same `Image` object. You need to use `Graphics.DrawImage` to perform an image scaling transformation.

Comment: Yes, Now I've used Graphics.DrawImage for scaling transformation.

Comment: When you have saved the Image to a MemoryStream, you just need `[MemoryStream].Position = 0` and `[bytes] = ms.ToArray()`. `scaledImage.RawFormat` should be substituted (in this context) by `ImageFormat.Png`

Comment: thank you all guys for the replies it really give me a better understanding on this situation really really big help but still now the problem became on viewing these columns on a datagridview it is throwing an sql exeption that im still working on more important thank you all for the replies really learned alot